# i need to post multiple json objects

Tags: android, retrofit

I need to post multiple json objects. i want to post this data to the server. I get null value. here i attached api and function.

my json object:

```
{
    "test_id":5,
    "user_id":null,
    "org_id":2,
    "schedule_id":15,
    "group_id":null,
    "next_section_id":"",
    "current_section":
       {

        }
    }
```

Here I attached api and function.
funtion :

```
try {
            JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject current_section = new JSONObject();

            paramObject.put("test_id", 5);
            paramObject.put("user_id", "null");
            paramObject.put("org_id", 2);
            paramObject.put("schedule_id", 15);
            paramObject.put("group_id", "null");


            paramObject.put("current_section",current_section);


            Call<Test_Responce> userCall = api_interface.testRes(paramObject);
            userCall.enqueue(new Callback<Test_Responce>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Test_Responce> call, Response<Test_Responce> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"else",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Test_Responce> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: can you post your whole code ?

Comment: where you getting null value?

Comment: `i get null value` where?

Comment: null value in paramobject

Comment: can you add null error log?

Answer (score 0):

Try using JsonObject from gson (dont use JSONObject)

```
JsonObject paramObject =new JsonObject();
paramObject.addProperty("test_id", 5);
paramObject.addProperty("user_id", "null");
paramObject.addProperty("org_id", 2);
paramObject.addProperty("schedule_id", 15);
paramObject.addProperty("group_id", "null");

JsonObject current_section =new JsonObject();
paramObject.add("current_section",current_section);
```

and change interface like this

```
@POST("take_tests")
Call<Test_Responce> testRes(@Body JsonObject paramObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`JSONObject.NULL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#NULL) instead of `"null"`, like

```
paramObject.put("user_id", JSONObject.NULL);
```